# getting static code analysis tool error "Calling a method on null object base.Request "

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-6.0, coverity

The static code analysis tool "Coverity" complains "Calling a method on null object base.Request" error (`var cid = Request.Headers["CId"];`) for below simple .NET 6 Web API controller API,

```
public class WeatherForecastController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet]
    public string Get()
    {
        var cid = Request.Headers["CId"];
        return cid.ToString();
    }
}
```

This means that "Request" object can be null.

1. I tried to avoid this using null-forgiving operator ! `var cid = Request!.Headers["CId"];`, it's saying same error.
2. Also tried null check for Request though it's saying always true `if (Request != null) { var cid = Request.Headers["CId"]; }`, even same error.

I know this I can ignore here as I know `Request` can never be `null` for my case.

Still wanted to know do we have any solution for it?

Comment: Not sure that null-forgiving operator will work for the custom static code analysis tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue seems to come from [`object.ToString`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.tostring?view=net-8.0) returning `string?`. There is nothing what can be null here [`ControllerBase.Request`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllerbase.request?view=aspnetcore-7.0) is not nullable, [`HttpRequest.Headers`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.httprequest.headers?view=aspnetcore-7.0) is not nullable also, (though `HttpRequest` has properties marked as nullable reference types like [`ContentType`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.httprequest.contenttype?view=aspnetcore-7.0#microsoft-aspnetcore-http-httprequest-contenttype)). [`IHeaderDictionary.Item[String]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.iheaderdictionary.item?view=aspnetcore-7.0) also returns non-nullable `StringValues`:

> The stored value, or `StringValues.Empty` if the key is not present.

Try:

```cs
return cid.ToString()!;
```

Or

```cs
var cid = Request?.Headers["CId"];
return cid?.ToString()!;
```